# Querying from room with many to many relationships

Tags: android, many-to-many, android-room

I have entities with many to many relationships.

```
@Entity
data class Exercise(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0L
    val name: String = "",
    val description: String = ""
)

@Entity
data class Round(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0L,
    val name: String = "",
    val reps: Int = 0
)

@Entity
data class ExerciseRound(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val exerciseId: Long = 0,
    val roundId: Long = 0,
    val weight: Int = 0
)
```

I can't figure out how to query from the room class which will contain all the exercises for the round with the fields from the ExerciseRound table. Something like that:

```
data class RoundExerciseRelation(
    @Embedded
    val round: Round,        
    val exerciseRelation: List<ExerciseRelation>
)

data class ExerciseRelation (
    val exercise: Exercise
    val roundData: ExerciseRound,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try with these you will get your Solution**

```
    @Query("SELECT name FROM tb_exercise where id IN ( SELECT roundId FROM tb_round where roundId IN ( SELECT roundId FROM tb_exercise_round where roundId=: roundId ")
    Maybe<List<String>> getExercise(String roundId);
(OR)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM tb_exercise where id IN ( SELECT roundId FROM tb_round where roundId IN ( SELECT roundId FROM tb_exercise_round where roundId=: roundId ")
    Maybe<List<Exercise>> getExercise(String roundId);
```

Comment: First one you will get List of Strings, Second one you will get list of Exercise Pojos

Answer (score 0):

This is how define one-to-many relation in Room

```
class RoundExerciseRelation {
    @Embedded
    val round: Round,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "package_id", entity = ExerciseRelation::class)
    val exerciseRelation: List<ExerciseRelation>

}
```

For may to many, we need to create a seperate table for storing the relation and use join query